# Dynamic routes sourced from the API are not appearing

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

When I create dynamic routes sourced from an API, it's not appearing in router and path /examplegrid cannot be accessed, I've added `router.addRoute`, but when I check the router, the data sourced from the API isn't there

```
//router/index.js

import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router';
import axiosInstance from '@/interceptors/axios.js';
import { api } from '@/api';
import Layout from '@/layout';
import Login from '@/login';
import store from '@/store';

const router = createRouter({
    history: createWebHistory(),
    routes: [
        {
            path: '/',
            component: Layout,
            children: [
                {
                    path: '',
                    component: () => import('@/views/Dashboard'),
                    meta: { requiresAuth: true, title: 'Dashboard' }
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            path: '/login',
            component: Login
        },
        {
            path: '/:catchAll(.*)',
            component: () => {
                window.location.href = '/pages/notfound.html';
            },
        },
    ],
});

async function createDynamicRoutes(userStamp, subsidiary, shouldCreateRoutes = true) {
    if (!shouldCreateRoutes) {
          return;
    }

    try {
        const response = await axiosInstance.post(
            api.dynamicRoutes.url,
            {
                UserStamp: userStamp,
                Subsidiary: subsidiary
            },
            {
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                },
            }
        );
   
        const data = response.data.menuPrivileges;

        if (!data) {
            return;
        }

        data.forEach(menuItem => {
            router.addRoute({
                path: menuItem.path,
                component: Layout,
                children: [
                    {
                        path: '',
                        component: () => import('@/views' + menuItem.component),
                        meta: { requiresAuth: true, title: menuItem.menuName }
                    }
                ]
            });
        });

        console.log(JSON.stringify(router.options.routes));
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching dynamic routes:', error);
    }
}

createDynamicRoutes('ABC', 'XYZ');

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    const isAuthenticated = store.state.isAuthenticated;

    if (to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresAuth)) {
        if (!isAuthenticated) {
            next({ path: '/login' });
        } else {
            next();
        }
    } else {
        next();
    }
});

export default router;
```

this API response,

```
{
"menuPrivileges":[
    {
    "menuName":"Example Entry",
    "status":"A",
    "component":"/Grid",
    "path":"/ExampleGrid"
    }
]
```

}

Comment: The obvious explanation is that addRoute doesn't mutate router.options. If there's a problem with dynamic routes, consider addressing them, looks like XY problem

Comment: `import('@/views' + menuItem.component)` Vite can't handle imports with alias (`@`), and dynamic string, but can if dynamic and relative. It's an underlying Rollup limitation.  Try `import('../views' + menuItem.component)` (or wherever relative component file exists)

Comment: @yoduh I've already tried those path and the data fetched from the API is still not included in the routes, there are alternative for creating dynamic routes?

Comment: @EstusFlask XY problem? what do you mean by XY problems?

Comment: See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem